# Laravel database query optimization

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have three tables related to `articles`  and i need to get `article_id` from them using `staff_id` i have.

I am currently using these three query.

```
  $rejects = DB::table('rejected')->where('staff_id', $staff_id)->pluck('article_id');
  $missed = DB::table('missed')->where('staff_id', $staff_id)->pluck('article_id');
  $flagged = DB::table('flagged')->where('staff_id', $staff_id)->pluck('article_id');
```

and then merging them

```
  $rejects = $rejects->toArray();
  $missed = $missed->toArray();
  $flagged = $flagged->toArray();

  $all = array_merge($rejects, $missed, $flagged);
```

In production my database will be in different server so I am trying to reduce the no of query.
How can I get this result using only one db query.

Comment: Have you tried using join statements?

Comment: with different servers and different databases it's not possible without special equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Use Eloquents by Laravel. Its really very useful. It will reduce the number of queries to a remarkable length plus no worries about the back-end DB engine. 
Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent